# A better way to handle async callbacks and rendering DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, nodemailer

I'm currently using `nodemailer` to send email from `reactjs` and following is my code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fullname: "",
      email: "",
      companyName: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      message: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { fullname, email, companyName, phoneNumber, message } = this.state;
    let form = await axios.post("/api/form", {
      fullname,
      email,
      companyName,
      phoneNumber,
      message
    });
    /**
     * I'm not proud of using jQuery in reactjs
     * Will need to get a better way to do this
     */

    if (form.status === 200) {
      $("#success").show();
      $("[name='fullname']").val("");
      $("[name='email']").val("");
      $("[name='companyName']").val("");
      $("[name='phoneNumber']").val("");
      $("[name='message']").val("");
  // As per comments and HS' answer
  this.setState({
    fullname: "",
    email: "",
    companyName: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    message: ""
  })
    }
  }
```

Now, the problem is jQuery and clearance of the form. How can I manipulate the DOM on `(form.status === 200)` i.e. to clear the form and show success message?

What I've done is the dirtiest way possible and is a hack. How would a ReactJS expert do it?

Comment: using setState would be how most people would approach this

Comment: You should not do direct DOM manipulation in React. Because React maintains a shadow DOM and does it's updates by comparing the changes in the shadow DOM. Keep each value like `fullname`, `email`, etc. in local state, and update the value as you need.

Comment: As @vahissan said you should not change the DOM as it is react's job. Just manipulate the virtual DOM using the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although people have commented already in the right direction, I would like to illustrate "what it means", presuming, you are new to ReactJS.

Step 1 - declare state variables for the input values in the form.

Step 2 - declare a state variable to control the visibility of "#success" element.

Ex.: `state = { showSuccess: false, fullname: "", email:"", companyName:"", phoneNumber:"", message:"" }`

Step 3 - Describe a proper render including the value of the input being set using the state variables. Also, the '#success' element should only be visible, if the state variable has 'truthful' value.

Ex.: `this.state.showSuccess && <div id='success'>Success</div>`, `<input type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={(e)=>this.setState({email:e.target.value})}/>`

Step 4 - Define the API caller and properly update the state.

Ex.: from the above example -

```
if (form.status === 200) {
      this.setState({showSuccess: true, fullname: "", email:"", companyName:"", phoneNumber:"", message:""})
    }
```

Comment: as a newbie dev I don't entirely understand, given the fact have `this.state` in `constructor` also, I get the point that `this.setState({})` should do the job\

Comment: HS, I have updated my code, can you demonstrate with an example, as I have tried `this.setState` and it is not working.

Comment: There is a simple example demonstrated here - https://codesandbox.io/s/8xj98r88nj

Comment: HS, thank you for the effort... I got your point of showing and hiding an element and I am doing it so, but my form elements are not clearing on submit

Comment: Your welcome. See this is the point, it won't clear on it's own. The strategy would be, as soon as you submit, you call 'this.setstate' to empty all the input fields.

Comment: Yes, I understood the point but the problem here is that `this.setState({})` isn't updating the state, after updating the state it, I console.log, let's say fullname, it returns undefines and the form value for fullname remains there

Comment: In case you are literally making the call to update the form using, `this.setState({})`, nothing will happen b'coz, you aren't updating anything in the state. So emptying should be done like this for a state variable `this.state.inputBoxVal` - `this.seState({inputBoxVal:""})`